# Callback is not Trigger when app is is background/Minimized

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, repository

I have Implemented MVVM architecture and it is working good when app is in foreground but when i minimize the app, repository send the data to view model and view model to activity but the callback is not called until i resume the application.
Method is Repository:

// Method for new order and its process, and listening the connects collection

```
fun connects(driverId: String, connectsSnapshot: (QuerySnapshot?) -> Unit) {
    if (connectsRef!=null){
        connectsRef?.remove()
        connectsRef=null
    }
    this.connectsSnapshot = connectsSnapshot
    connectsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("connects").whereEqualTo("driver_id", UserDto.getInstance().id).whereEqualTo("status", "new").orderBy("created", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
    .addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
        if (e != null) {
            connectsSnapshot (null)
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        System.out.println("==>ListnerHit")
        connectsSnapshot (snapshots)
    }
}
```

this one send data to view model

```
val mutableLiveDataForConnect = MutableLiveData<QuerySnapshot>()
    val mObserverForConnect: Observer<QuerySnapshot> = Observer {
        getView().connectListener(it)
    }


 fun getConnectsData(driverId: String)
    {
         repository.connects(driverId){
             mutableLiveDataForConnect.postValue(it)
             System.out.println("==>ViewModel")
         }
    }
```

this one also get called but i am not able to receive the data on activity when app is minimized. it  works fine when i move the code to acitivty but i need to move the code to repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LiveData doesn't get new values without an active Observer, and when you minimise your app the Observer gets paused, because it is lifecycle dependent. Once the app gets back to the foreground, the Observer returns to the active state, the latest data gets posted to it and your activity is updated. This is how LiveData and Observers are supposed to work.

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do. Why is it necessary to update the activity while it's not visible to anyone? It sounds like you are trying to do something in the activity/Observer that's not supposed to be happening there with MVVM.

Comment: the purpose to get live data even any of the activity is view while home view will always stay open on back stack. same code works fine in other app but not in this. is there a way to achieve this ??